# indexing hierarchical data in hibernate search

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

How to use hibernate search over a hierarchical structure..

Following is the structure that I am using..

Each Contact has a Location,i.e town info but Location is a hierarchical table eg. (country->state->city->town )

Need the ability to search for Contacts that directly or indirectly fall under country named USA..

How do I go ahead doing such configuration using hibernate search ?

Any comments, links, samples will be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I replied on the Hibernate forums:
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2453793#p2453793

A quick draft:

```
@Entity @Indexed
public class Contact {

...//all fields

   @IndexedEmbedded
   Location getLocation() {
      return location;
   }
}

@Entity @Indexed
public class Location {

...// all location fields, such as address, postal code, etc..

   @IndexedEmbedded
   Town getTown() {
      return town;
   }
}
```